# Checking a procedure reference for type?

Tags: oop, scheme, racket

We are using scheme version r5rs trying to check a procedure pointer for the type it is pointing to.

We've created a object using:

```
(define (%macro name exp env)
  (define (set-exp new_exp) (set! exp new_exp))
  (define (set-env new_env) (set! env new_env))
  (define (set-name new_name) (set! name new_name))

  (define (%dispatch call)
    (cond 
      ((eq? call 'get-exp) exp)
      ((eq? call 'get-env) env)
      ((eq? call 'get-name) name)

      ((eq? call 'set-exp) set-exp)
      ((eq? call 'set-env) set-env)
      ((eq? call 'set-name) set-name)
  ))

  %dispatch
)
```

We then want to check a procedure reference to determine if it points to the dispatch function in another part of the code:

```
(define (macro? exp)
  (eq? %macro exp)
  )
```

This doesn't seem to work, how do we properly check the pointer if it points to a macro object (really the dispatch procedure)?

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps add one more method to your object that responds to 'macro?.  In the terms of a Java programmer: avoid instanceof calls.  If all your objects follow a common protocol like implementing a macro? method, would that solve the problem?

In more featureful languages like full Racket, using a [structure type property](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/structprops.html#%28tech._structure._type._property%29) would also work.  Since you're deliberately in r5rs, your options are more limited.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm afraid I can't use full Racket since my university currently limits us to using r5rs. The 'macro would unfortunetly nmot resolve it since all my objects sent ot "macro?" are not able to respond to such queries.

Comment: Hmmm.  Can you have all your objects support a "type" method that returns their constructor?  What restrictions do you have in what you can change?